# Can I set units in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4DUN.png)

I want to adjust the unit spacing of the red borders in the photo
For example, I want to adjust the units in 70 steps like 70,140,210. Is this possible? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to this

```
tempLineChart = findViewById(R.id.temp_lineChart);
YAxis yAxisleft = tempLineChart.getAxisLeft();
yAxisleft.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {

            return value+"℃";
        }
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTFmA.jpg)

Comment: How to format the line value ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73706679/how-to-change-the-entry-label-in-line-chart

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your design using **BarChart**

**BarChart** on **MPAndroidChart** library

[image]

Step 1 : Add Library To build.gradle

Step 2 : Add this code to the Content Page

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
    android:id="@+id/chart1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Step 3 : Follow the Java codes at this [link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivity.java)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer
But I already implemented
Like the picture, I want the number of the red border on the left to be 70, 140, 210 .. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use chart.getAxisLeft() function to get the axis then set parameters using functions
setAxisMaximum(float min),setAxisMinimum(float min),setLabelCount(int count, boolean force) etc.
Refer https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/axis-general/ for more details.

Comment: Let me know by voting the ans if that worked for you.